# Create React App + Contentful infinite request loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, contentful

I started to follow the following tutorial:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-a-headless-cms-with-react/

Unfortunately once I completed it I noticed my `Network` tab in chrome started going crazy AFTER I navigated to one of the child items:

Here is the reduced code version: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-contentful-hx0de?from-embed

I figured it must be how its being called from Contentful in this snippet that uses a promise to get the results:

```
export default function useSinglePost(slug) {
  const promise = getSinglePost(slug);

  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    promise.then(result => {
      setPost(result[0].fields);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [promise]);

  return [post, isLoading];
}
```

But I cant figure out why I get this infinite loop of network requests.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
export default function useSinglePost(slug) {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSinglePost(slug)
     .then(result => {
      setPost(result[0].fields);
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [slug]);

  return [post, isLoading];
}
```

U have `const promise = getSinglePost(slug);` without any memo or something.
So, In the `useEffect` when promise resolves u perform state changes. Causing rerender. And on those rerenders promise gets redefind changes the `promise`. Again causing `useEffect` to run. Which again causes state change and rerender and heres ur infinite LOOP

Comment: Hi Thanks for helping me out. But then promise will be undefined right?